# Usar Internet móvil mientras uso Wifi en red local

Tags: java, android

en mi proyecto mi APP Android se conecta mediante Wifi a una Raspberry para recibir información. El problema es que mientras hace esto como el teléfono detencta que esta conectado a una red wifi aunque esta no tenga conexión a internet no utiliza el internet móvil para tener conexión.

¿Hay alguna forma de conseguir que el teléfono use los datos móviles para tener aceso a internet mientras esta conectado a esta red wifi local sin acceso a internet? No quiero que mientras uso la app el telefono se quede sin recibir correos electronicos o whatsapps. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible usar 2 tipos de conexiones diferentes, no se puede usar Wi-Fi y datos móviles a la vez, aunque la red Wi-Fi no tenga acceso a Internet solo se puede conectar de 1 forma a la vez.

Sin embargo puedes intentar esto:

- Poner Internet a la red Wi-Fi
- Emitir tu red Wi-Fi desde tu móvil, y probar tu app desde otro dispositivo conectado a tu red Wi-Fi.

Las opciones son limitadas, pero esto te puede servir de algo.